# Duplicate records two calls on database

Tags: c#

How can I avoid duplicate invoke to database. First time I wanna get duplicate records but in second invoke I want to skip records but without invoke _context again. This example of my code:

```
var duplicateCustomers = customerObject.Customers.
     Where(a => _context.Customers.Any(b => a.CustomerId == b.CustomerIdRef && customerObject.ClientId == b.ClientId));

var skipDuplicateCustomers = customerObject.Customers.
     Where(a => !_context.Customers.Any(b => a.CustomerId == b.CustomerIdRef && customerObject.ClientId == b.ClientId));
```

These data comes from json via customerObject.I need to check do customers exsists in db if not they need to be save to logger and they are not duplicate from this cusotmerOBject need to be added in customers table.

I need to separate lists(duplicate, not duplicate) but with one call to database.

Comment: Did you try `Distinct()`?

Comment: No distinct does not working in this case. I need skipDuplicate but from result of first query..

Comment: Can you give a little more context about you really need? It looks like a probelm that can be solved with Distinct. Why you need to use the results of the first query?

Comment: These data comes from json via customerObject.I need to check do customers exsists in db if not they need to be save to logger and they are not duplicate from this cusotmerOBject need to be added in customers table.

Comment: It looks like you'll just end up with all customer records, split by whether or not they match the query?  Maybe the group by operator can do what you want? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.groupby?view=netframework-4.8